# Why the Variadic Constructor with std::is_constructible Fails to Handle Initializer List Initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a C++11 class named `Prop` that looks like this:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Prop {
public:
    template <typename... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value>::type>
    Prop(Args &&...args) {
        const auto val = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        getter = [=]() { return val; };
    }

    T operator()() const {
        return getter();
    }

private:
    std::function<T()> getter;
};
```

When I try to create a `Prop` object with an initializer list like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto prop = Prop<std::vector<int>>({ 1, 2, 3 });
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error like this:

```
/Users/tempus/Desktop/liquid/src/main.cpp:32:17: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Prop<std::vector<int>>'
    auto prop = Prop<std::vector<int>>({ 1, 2, 3 });
                ^                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/tempus/Desktop/liquid/src/main.cpp:5:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const Prop<std::vector<int>>'
class Prop {
      ^
/Users/tempus/Desktop/liquid/src/main.cpp:5:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'Prop<std::vector<int>>'
class Prop {
      ^
/Users/tempus/Desktop/liquid/src/main.cpp:14:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <(no value)> for template parameter 'Args'
    Prop(Args &&...args) {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

However, if I add the following constructor to the `Prop` class:

```cpp
template <typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>>::value>::type>
Prop(const std::initializer_list<U> &list) {
    const auto val = T(list);
    getter = [=]() { return val; };
}
```

the error goes away, and the code compiles successfully.

In the case of `auto prop = Prop<std::vector<int>>({ 1, 2, 3 });`, the `Args` type should be deduced as `std::initializer_list<int>`, and `std::vector<int>` is constructible from `std::initializer_list<int>`. So, I would expect the `Prop(Args &&...args)` constructor to handle this case.

Why does the absence of the `std::initializer_list` constructor cause a compilation error when creating a Prop object with an initializer list, even though the `Prop(Args &&...args)` constructor seems to be a match for `std::initializer_list<int>`? What is the role of the `std::initializer_list` constructor in this case, and why is it necessary for the code to compile successfully?

Comment: *I get a compilation error.* What error? Please post it verbatim.

Comment: With your example, I get the `error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'`. Be kind to post a [mcve].

Comment: Perfect forwarding is imperfect in forwarding initializer lists. [temp.deduct.call](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.call): *Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context ([temp.deduct.type]).*

Comment: side issue: incorrect usage of std::enable_if, see code example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) under section `Notes`

Comment: Fwiw, I think you mostly need another type-trait: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/j1j9Wb19o)

Comment: @TedLyngmo You saved my life <3